# Sublime Text freezes

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text2 to edit my node js app. It freezes often and the only thing that worked is a reboot. I tried using task manager to close sublime text but failed. Even the node JS app server isn't turning on. I tried killing the process and service but no success. I was using sublimetext3 before and that too created the same problem.

Comment: I don't use sublime text anymore, but i suspect it has something to do with the node_modules folder and it trying to index it. There's likely some way to tell it to ignore certain folders, so telling it to ignore node_modules might be a good idea. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @KevinB works as I am not seeing the problem crop up again. So I thought the following [coderwall link](http://coderwall.com/p/dza-mw/exclude-files-folders-in-sublime-text) might help others as well. 
Thanks!